# Python invalid syntax on def

Tags: python, syntax, twisted

I'm trying to set up a UDP server with Twisted folliowing this http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html

However, I've hit a brickwall just starting. I tried this sample code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(DatagramProtocol):

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)
        self.transport.write(data, (host, port))

reactor.listenUDP(9999, Echo())
reactor.run()
```

And I get this:

```
def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to Python so I'm clueless. I stripped the code down to the minimum, commenting everything but the class declaration and the method header (adding a pass) but I get the same. Are those paired parameters not supported anymore?

Comment: What Python version are you using?  Also, are you sure there isn't an indentation error?

Comment: 2.7, and there are 4 spaces on every indent.

Comment: That syntax was removed in Python 3, but still works in Python 2.7.  Are you absolutely sure that: a) the code is being run with Python 2.7 (i.e., do you also have a Python 3 installed that might be running instead); b) the code you pasted is exactly the code you are running?

Comment: That's right. Python 3 is the one doing the job, so it won't allow the double parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's python 2.7. Because [PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) describes the removal of that syntax in Python 3. As a test when I run the below dummy function in python 2.7 it works. In Python 3.2 it gives me your exact same error:

```
def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
    pass
```

python 3 error:

```
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

try this in your code just to be sure of your python version:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: I think this was it. I had told PyDev to use 2.7 grammar so I assumed it would interpret it as 2.7 code. Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: I have a question on this one, anyone know how to adapt this code for python3?  Im on an upgrade from python2 to 3 for my programs